# Convergence of $\sum_{n≥ 1}(n^{{n}^{\alpha}}-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n≥ 1}(n^{{n}^{\alpha}}-1)$$
for $\alpha>0$. What I did was to take an arbitrary sequence in this case $b_n=n^{\alpha}\ln(n)$, if I'm not wrong it is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{{n}^{\alpha}}-1}{n^{\alpha}\ln(n)}=1.$$
In this way, using the comparison test it remains to determine for which values $b_n$ converges, however I do not know how to do it, any help? thanks.

Comment: $n^{n^\alpha}$ grows much faster than $n^\alpha\ln(n)$.  The divergence of this series is much simpler.

Comment: Did you check whether the series sequence even converges to zero...?

Comment: If $\alpha>0$ then $n^{n^\alpha}-1>n^{n^0}-1=n-1$. Can you conclude?

Comment: When $\alpha>0,$ $n^\alpha>1$ and thus $$n^{n^\alpha}-1> n-1,$$ so the series doesn’t converge. Don’t need anything fancy.

Comment: “…if I’m not wrong…” You are wrong. $(e^x-1)/x\to1$ as $x\to 0,$ so you get your limit as $n\to0,$ but not as $x\to\infty,$ so not as $n\to\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

The approximation $e^x\approx 1+x$ holds for small $x$, i.e. when $x\to 0$, $e^x=1+x+o(x^2)$. So, to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{n^\alpha}-1}{n^\alpha\ln n}=1,$$
you'd need that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha\ln n=0$. This isn't true for any $\alpha>0$.

Now, what happens to $e^x-1$ when $x$ doesn't tend to $0$? Can you use this to show that the terms of your series don't converge to $0$?